# What is this convention of using php code inside the first html tags?

Tags: php, html, drupal-7

I was referring the page.tpl.php(Drupal 7 theme) for understanding the code. I found the following code,

```
<?php if ($site_name || $site_slogan): ?>
        <!-- !Site name and Slogan -->
        <div<?php print $hgroup_attributes; ?>>

          <?php if ($site_name): ?>
            <h1<?php print $site_name_attributes; ?>><?php print $site_name; ?></h1>
          <?php endif; ?>

          <?php if ($site_slogan): ?>
            <h2<?php print $site_slogan_attributes; ?>><?php print $site_slogan; ?></h2>
          <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can you see the code in third line, `<div<?php print $hgroup_attributes; ?>>` WHY the php code is inside the first div tag of html? Same thing in later part of code also, as you can see h1 and h2 code. So, **what is this convention of combining the html and php in so complicated way? and how should I read that?**

Comment: If you're echoing html tag attributes from a PHP variable to an HTML tag, then those attributes have to be inside the tag, that's how html tag attributes work..... e.g. `<div class="divstyle">....</div>` where `$hgroup_attributes;` is a string with a value of ` class="divstyle"`

Comment: I got it somewhat, means that class value is coming from that php variable, hence instead of writing class="divstyle", I need to write that php variable directly there, so div will have the class value but it comes from php variable. right?

Comment: Ok, I got you `<div<?php print $hgroup_attributes; ?>>` will convert to `<div class="divstyle">` after php code do printing..

Comment: Can you put it as a answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining HTML and PHP code in Drupal templates is actually a very strong feature. In this case, `$hgroup_attributes` will probably contain some classes that style the `div`. Printing it in the template results in something like

```
<div class="SOME_CLASSES"> ... </div>
```

If you're further interested in the variable `$hgroup_attributes`, you can inspect by pasting `<?php dpm($hgroup_attributes); ?>` in your template file after you've installed the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module.